# Mostrar imágenes con condicional

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-5

tengo **5** imágenes con los números del uno al cinco respectivamente, pero solo quiero que se muestren, dependiendo de la cantidad de eventos que estén en el otro label.

**Código en la vista parcial: primer**

@*columnas*@

```
    <td> <img src="~/Content/Admin/One_White.png" style=" width:50px;height:80px;max-width:100%;max-height:100%" /> </td>
        <td> <img src="~/Content/Admin/Two_White.png" style=" width:50px;height:80px;max-width:100%;max-height:100%" /> </td>
        <td> <img src="~/Content/Admin/Three_White.png" style=" width:50px;height:80px;max-width:100%;max-height:100%" /> </td>
        <td> <img src="~/Content/Admin/Four_White.png" style=" width:50px;height:80px;max-width:100%;max-height:100%" /> </td>
        <td> <img src="~/Content/Admin/Five_White.png" style=" width:50px;height:80px;max-width:100%;max-height:100%" /> </td>
</tr>
```

**Código vista parcial: Segundo**

```
 <tr >
    @if (Model != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <td> <label> <strong> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;@item.Name&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; </strong>  </label> </td>
        }
    }
</tr>
```

**Una imagen para mayor entendimiento**
en este caso la idea es que ni el número 4 ni el número 5 aparezcan en pantalla ya que solo tengo 3 accione y así para todos los items que pueden tener 3 o más acciones.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Controlador

```
 public ActionResult OptionWizardDataPartial(int id)
    {
        var typeEvent = AdminDataProvider.GetDataSyncById(id); 
        var events = AdminDataProvider.GetEventsByTypeEvents(typeEvent);

        return PartialView("_OptionWizard", events);
    }
```

Comment: Y cómo obtienes las acciones? Sería bueno que pongas ese código.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías probar con el objeto que trae el Modelo (Model)... Osea en Model pones un objeto que tenga la img y el nombre, dependiendo de las acciones que tengas creas mas o menos objetos con sichas imágenes, en la vista solo tiene que hacerle el foreach y meterle la etiqueta

No sé como consigues las acciones

Answer (score 0):

Podrias iterar el Model tanto al generar los numeros como al mostrar los textos, entonces en ambas filas mostrarias la misma cantidad de columnas

algo como ser

```
@{
   Dictionary<int, string> lista = new Dictionary<int, string>()
   {
       {1, "One_White.png"},
       {2, "Two_White.png"},
       //resto
   };

   int i = 0;
}

<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <td> 
                <img src="~/Content/Admin/@lista[i]" style=" width:50px;height:80px;max-width:100%;max-height:100%" /> 
            </td>
            @i++;
        }
    </tr>

    <tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <td> 
            <label> <strong> @item.Name </strong>  </label> 
        </td>
    }
    </tr>
</table>
```

con el Dictionary<> puedes mapear un index con el nombre del archivo para reemplazarlo en el `src` del `img` y asi hacerlo dinamico